# Move record to Archived View Not soft delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add an Archive button to a table so when it is clicked the data in that row moves to a different view called archive, I have Edit and delete all figured out.. Unlike soft delete the record will just move from index to Archived view. It might be simple but I don't know how. 
I don't know if I need a new model for archived or new column in my table that says is archived, but as i mentioned, archive button should only move the record to a different view that has all archived record, maybe i need to create a new table in the data base for all archived data from the main table.. here is what i have so far:
View:

```
@model IEnumerable<practice2.Models.Customer>
@{


                ViewBag.Title = "Archive";
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Archive</h2>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th> User Name</th>

                <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                <th>Membership Type</th>
                <th>Email</th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)

            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.LastName, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                    <td>@customer.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@customer.MembershipType.NameOfMembershipType</td>
                    <td>@customer.EmailAddress</td>


                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Archive (int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Customer customer = _context.Customer.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            _context.Customer.Move(customer)to archive;// I wish it was       this easy

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
        }
```

thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can go 2 ways here, depending on how you wanna work with the data afterwards. Create a new Archive table as you suggest or simply add an extra column to your current Customer table.

If you create a new table you first copy the needed values from your Customer table to your Archive table and then delete the data from the Customer table.

Or, you add an extra column to the Customer table e.g. IsArchived, and make it a bool (bit in SqL). Set to true for "Customer is archived" or false if not.
Then you can filter your customers in the different Controllers based on this value.

If you already have data in the table make it a nullable bool (bool?) - (SqL - Allow Null) and treat null-values as false.

**Edit**

> In Case People have same question:

**IN Model ADD:**

```
public bool? IsArchived { set; get; }
```

**Nu-get**

```
Add-migration AddNewColumnToWhatever
Update-database
```

**In Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Archive(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Customer customer = _context.Customer.Find(id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            customer.IsArchived = true;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");


        }


        public ActionResult GetCustomers(string typeOfCustomer)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeOfCustomer))
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            if (typeOfCustomer == "archived")
            {
                customers = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.MembershipType).Where(x => x.IsArchived == true).Select(x => x).ToList();
            }

            else if (typeOfCustomer == "active")
            {
                customers = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.MembershipType).Where(x => x.IsArchived == false).Select(x => x).ToList();
            }

            else
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(customers);
        }
```

**Create a new view for GetCustomers and define the model there to be:**

```
@model List<YourProject.FolderWhereYourClassIsDefined.Customer>
```

And build your view as you want it to be.

In your existing view, place 2 buttons to call the new ActionResult.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Archived", "GetCustomers", "Customers", new { typeOfCustomer = "archived" }, new { @class = "btn" })
@Html.ActionLink("View Active", "GetCustomers", "Customers", new { typeOfCustomer = "active" }, new { @class = "btn" })//You don't need it
```

**Now in index controller do THIS:**

```
var customer = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.MembershipType)
                .Where(c => c.IsArchived == null)// important
                .Where(c => c.IsArchived == false) // important
                .Include(c => c.CardType)
                .ToList();//to excute query immediatly
```

You should be all good. LasseHolm/EndlessQ

Comment: I created this "public bool? IsArchived { set; get; }" in the model. In Archive action i changed  "_context.Customer.IsArchived = true;" To "customer.IsArchived = true;"  And In GetCustomers it says active and archived has no value when i set it to  private string archived; which is always null. so in the view nothing happens when i click "Archive" and when i click the btn you gave me i get 404.

Comment: Realized I had forgotten a select statement before each ToList() - see updated code. That should do the trick. For both buttons, if you use bootstrap css I think you should put @class = “btn” + whatever extra styling you Line. Not “button” which I put in for demonstration purpose. Also you are right, _context should be left out in the set to true part. Not easy doing code while away from the editor ...

Comment: oh! The 404... did you create a GetCustomers view to display the List<Customer> ?

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help help. I have 2 issues now: 1) when i hit Archive btn the record doesn't disappear from Index eventhough in the data base IsArchived is checked so the archive controller works fine. (2) In GetCustomer View i get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error for the @foreach(var customer in Model) model is null even though it is not..